# Out Of Memory Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm trying to create my first android app, so I'm really new to android development. I'm trying to make a nice background image for my app. I made an image that is the exact dimensions of the device, but when I try to load it, i get the error "Failed to allocate a 218748 byte allocation with 217220 free bytes and 212KB until OOM" Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    drawBackground(canvas);

protected void drawBackground(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background2));
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
```

I've tried scaling it down, which works, but then it doesn't fill the entire screen. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you have a look at the [background](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background) xml attribute or the [setBackgroundResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) method int the `View` class? Unless you need to draw custom content - which I don't think it's your case - one or the other should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should recycle bitmap after `canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);`, or create bitmap once, in the constructor, and then use it, it is very costly to create bitmap each time in the onDraw method, it even costly to create simple objects in the onDraw, you shuold avoid from it, `android:largeHeap="true"` and `System.gc()` can't help in this case. Read this
[Custom Drawing](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

> Creating objects ahead of time is an important optimization. Views are redrawn very frequently, and many drawing objects require expensive initialization. Creating drawing objects within your onDraw() method significantly reduces performance and can make your UI appear sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

There is blog that will help you to detect and prevent Out of memory issue. I wrote this based on a real problem I faced and here is the [link](http://blogs.innovationm.com/android-out-of-memory-error-causes-solution-and-best-practices/)

If you got stuck anywhere in the tutorial please let me know we can discuss and if you want to add something please suggest.